# Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies

Tags: asp.net

Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.
i am getting this error after uploaded my application on server. The same application works fine on local.i have used vs 2010,asp.net for the same

Comment: upload again `AjaxControlToolkit` dll in the `Bin` folder on the server. May be the uploaded version and the one you are using on local are different.

Comment: sorry but this wont work

Comment: does your server support .NET 4.0 ?